# Make files read-only unless accessed by symlink path

Tags: linux, macos, file-permissions, symlink, readonly

Say I have a folder tree like:

```
root/
  ro/
  symlink-to-ro/
```

my question is two-fold:

(a) is there a way to make all files in the ro directory read-only, but if the files are accessed by way of the symlink, make them writable?

(b) the reverse of (a): is there a way to make the files writable only if they are accessed directly?

This is just for *nix/MacOS

Comment: Do you have a use case for this, or is it pure curiosity? If you have a use case, we might come up with an alternative way to do the same thing.

Comment: @Amadan well the only alternative I can think of is just `rsync -r`, but the problem with that is the y don't mirror each other when the original files change which they will.

Comment: I can see by rep you are not a newbie, so I was trying to be a bit more circumspect in suggesting this might be an XY problem :) I don't mean "alternative to access control by path", I meant are you sure your underlying problem can't be solved with the usual permission system, groups, and/or ACL, or maybe some other method? What is the scenario you are trying to use this in?

Comment: Yeah I am mostly curious, if there are any good solutions related to the question, they are relevant. Basically, I am trying to prevent someone from making changes to a file that will get overwritten later by a command line tool. The tool spits out files, the files will be read-only, or there will be some mechanism to tell the user that modifying the files is a waste of time b/c they will be overwritten later.

Comment: Linux usually does that just with comments inside the autogenerated file, and trusts users with sudo authority not to be idiots :D If the tool is a binary executable, you can set it to setgid with a group that has write permissions to the directory. e.g. `drwxrwxr-x amadan writable file`, with `drwxrwsrwx amadan writable utility`; this would allow only members of `writable` group to edit the file, as well as the `utility`, regardless of the user who runs it.

Answer (score 2):

No. Permissions are assigned to inodes, not to directory entries; so the same set of permissions is checked regardless of the path you used to access the file.

EDIT: Scratch that. I just remembered there *is* a way: while files and folders don't carry permissions, *mounts* can be set to be readonly. If you were on Linux, a [read-only bind mount](https://askubuntu.com/questions/243380/how-to-create-a-read-only-link-to-a-directory) would be exactly what you are looking for. AFAIK OSX can't do that, so you can fake it with an [NFS mount](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/197029/how-do-you-mount-bind-a-local-directory) (not as nice).